# 1.15 - 1.13 = 0.01999998 or 0.02?

Tags: vb.net, precision

I have the following code in two different projects on the same pc:

```
Dim MySingle1 As Single = 1.15
Dim MySingle2 As Single = 1.13
Dim MyResult As Single = MySingle1 - MySingle2
```

But the most interesting thing is, in one project `MyResult` is 0.02 and in another project `MyResult` is 0.01999998.

I failed to solve this. Please offer me suggestions.

Thanking you in advance.

Regards
SKPaul

Comment: Did you also check the value of `MyResult` in the exact same way in both cases? It would seem that in the other case you're losing precision, as `0.01999998` looks like a more precise value.

Comment: Thanks Matti, everything is same in both cases. I am checking it in debugging mode.

Comment: Have you checked other numbers. eg Check whether 1/3 is 0.33 in one project and 0.33333333 in another? You must have some setting different that is rounding up the value. ps 0.01999998 is the value you should get via binary maths, 0.02 is this rounded up.

Answer (score 3):

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

To make the story short, computers cannot exactly represent most floating point numbers. They work on approximations.

Comment: That doesn't explain why taking (supposedly) the exactly same steps in the same environment result in different results. Floating point numbers are imprecise, but the imprecision is predictable.

Comment: @Matti - that's a common misconception.  It is not predictable on 32-bit machines, the jitter optimizer in the Release build can leave intermediate results stored in FPU registers with 80 bits of precision.  Not a problem with the 64-bit jitter.  Computations with Single (float) will only ever have 6.5 significant digits, the rest is just noise.

Comment: @Hans: The guy said he was using a debugger though. That kind of optimization shouldn't kick in in debug builds, right?

Answer (score 0):

Floating point uses internally a base-2 representation. For single precision, that is 24 bits, which is roughly equivalent to ~(6,7) decimal digits of precision, which is what you are getting (your seventh digit is inexact).

Comment: how should i handle it? MyResult.Tosting("0.00") ? or any other way??